# Soundness and Completeness

Tags: debugging, math, logic, analysis

I'm taking a software analysis class and was asked the following question.  It has to do with programming logic thus the reason why I posted it here.  (I also posted this to the math stack overflow site as well.):

[image: Program Space]

Suppose the SHADED portion denotes all programs that do NOT contain divide-by-zero errors, and the UNSHADED portion within the black rectangle denotes all programs that DO contain such errors.

Let A1, A2, and A3 be different program analyses which check for divide-by-zero errors.  Each analysis either ACCEPTS (i.e. declares it free of divide-by-zero errors) or REJECTS (i.e. declares that at least one divide-by-zero error exists in) a given program.

For each analysis, the programs accepted by that analysis are contained INSIDE the corresponding oval, and the programs rejected by that analysis are contained OUTSIDE the corresponding oval.

With reference to Question 4, suppose we design an analysis A4 which behaves as follows on input program P:

```
if (A1 rejects P) reject P;
else if (A3 accepts P) accept P; 
else run forever;
```

Is A4 sound?  Is A4 complete?

I chose A4 was sound because A1 accepts Programs which are valid and rejects those which are not.  This was marked correct. I said it was not complete because A4 did not accept programs which were indeed valid programs and was marked wrong.  Wondering if someone could shed a little light on this for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that it would be complete. Say you have a program that gives a DBZ error and we want to test this. Send that program to A1. A1 contains the space of both programs with and without DBZ. So it could be accepted by A1, or rejected by A1. If it is rejected by A1, then we can reject the program as having a DBZ error. If it is not rejected by A1 then go to A3, which only accepts programs without DBZ errors. Remember this is for programs that were not rejected by A1. If the program is accepted by A3, then we know that it does not have a DBZ error. If it is rejected here also, we know that it contains a DBZ error.

Essentially using A1 alone cannot fully determine whether or not the program will be accepted. But since A3 only contains the space of programs that can be accepted, if it is accepted in A1 and in A3 we can deduce that it is a valid program.

From this explanation, it seems that if a program was valid, it would be accepted by A3 even if A1 does not catch the program as being invalid since A3 will only accept valid programs, which is the opposite of what you said to why A4 cannot be complete.

Let me know if I should clarify some points in this answer.

Comment: Hi Edeki, thanks for the response.  I believe there is a set that is valid but is not included in both the set (A1 rejects) and the set (A3 accepted)-- that is the set (Programs without DBZ errors minus A3).  The presence of this set I believe makes A4 not complete???

Comment: Don’t think that’s possible based on the diagram. Since A3 only accepts programs that are valid based on the diagram (fully shaded) if A1 rejects but A3 accepts then it has to be valid since A3 has no white space. The set you are referring to is empty based on the diagram

Comment: The program doesn't have to necessarily terminate.  Could it not just run on forever in an infinite loop never returning an answer either way?  A1 and A3 do not contain the whole program space is what I'm getting at.  A3 is just a subset of the actually valid program space.

Comment: If for example a program is outside of A3 but inside of the shaded area and never changes.  Then the program will never return.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: A follow up on this, my professor explained that the "soundness" and "completeness" of analysis is based upon the type of the analysis not the end result of the analysis, which I was thinking the analysis was based upon.  Thank you to @Edeki you got it